# How can I run two CCActions in parallel and another one afterwards with Cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d

With Cocos2D I can run two actions in parallel by simply using `runAction` and I can use a `CCSequence` two run several actions after each other.
However what I could not find is:

- Run two actions simultaneously
- When both actions are done, trigger a third `CCAction`

It must be really easy but I seem to use the wrong search keywords on Google. :-)

The only possible solution I have found so far is to use a delayed action as the first element of a CCSequence and then start the third action. But it "feels" wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code (cocos2dx v3.x):

```
node->runAction( Sequence::create( Spawn::create(A, B, nullptr),
                                    C,
                                    nullptr));
```

This is what happen:

1. A and B start simultaneously
2. After the longer one finished, C start.

Important: Remember that you should use finite action when using `Sequence`. for example you should not use `RepeatForever` for actions when use them in `Sequence`.

---

cocos2d v2.x

```
node->runAction( CCSequence::create( CCSpawn::create(A, B, NULL),
                                    C,
                                    NULL));
```